# Generating pdf using itextsharp in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

I want to generate pdf file as attached in the picture. i want to harcode the contents shown in the picture into a pdf file on button click.

How do i proceed, using table structure will work?I am unable to form the table stucture here.

Please help me to sort out my problem.i want the output as shown in below image.

[image]

Comment: It seems like you are posting your customer/boss/teacher requirements and expecting someone else doing your job. At least show some efforts. Try something first, show what you have tried and what kind of problems you have encountered so that we have a base for discussion. Right know we have a scanned photo.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not Google ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create one table with two columns like below

```
_______________________________________________
|                             |               |
|                             |               |
|                             |               |
|           COL.0.1           |    COL.0.2    |
|                             |               |
|                             |               |
-----------------------------------------------
```

keep reference to its columns, then create table for left side content and insert it as child content of left column COL.0.1

```
------------------------------
| designation: xxxxxxx        |   <---- colspan = 2
------------------------------
| Audit No.        |    xxxx  |
------------------------------
| Received on .......         |
-------------------------------
```

and you can continue for the rest of content similar to this.

The idea is to split content to smaller tables and nest them.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a good tutorial about using iTextSharp

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Category/20